# How do I set up label/value when using JuiceUI's AutoComplete control from codebehind?

Tags: juice-ui

The JuiceUI AutoComplete control accepts a string[] for the Source property, yet in documentation it says you can use label/value pairs. I'm not very familiar with the jQuery autocomplete stuff to begin with, and after searching for a while I can't seem to find the correct syntax to make this work. Can anyone help me out? I'm looking for something like this:

```
UserAutoComplete.Source = users.Select(u => new { label = u.Id, value = u.Name});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch. Please file this as an issue here: https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/issues and we'll get a fix in there for the next release.

In the mean time, I'd use a separate map to map labels to actual values. It's a bit hackey, but it'll get you by until we update, and it'll be an easy transition with the updated code.